# Filtering data.table based on values in group of variables

Tags: r, data.table

I ran into a problem with finding the best syntax to filter out cases where I want to filter all rows where a group of variables has at least one value non null.

An example is below:

```
> dat <- data.table(a=1:5, b=c(1:3, NA, NA), c=c(NA, 1:3, NA))

> cols <- c('b', 'c')

> dat[!all(is.na(cols)), .SD, with=FALSE]
Null data.table (0 rows and 0 cols)

> dat[!is.na(b)|!is.na(c), .SD]
   a  b  c
1: 1  1 NA
2: 2  2  1
3: 3  3  2
4: 4 NA  3
```

As you can see if I explicitly say each variable name as `!is.na(variable1) | !is.na(variable2)` it works however I can't find a way to include a group of variables so I can do it in 1 condition only and not concatenate everything with `or`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following syntax with `rowSums` and `.SD`:

```
dat[dat[, rowSums(!is.na(.SD)) > 0, .SDcols  = cols]]
#   a  b  c
#1: 1  1 NA
#2: 2  2  1
#3: 3  3  2
#4: 4 NA  3
```

The inner part creates a logical value that looks like this:

```
dat[, rowSums(!is.na(.SD)) > 0, .SDcols  = cols]
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Re the comment by Michael, you can also use `Reduce` + `lapply`:

```
dat[dat[, Reduce("+", lapply(.SD, function(x) !is.na(x))) > 0, .SDcols = cols]]
```

But for most of my use cases, the `rowSums` approach is ok and easier to read, imo.

Comment: works, but matrix conversion is expensive on large data. there's a Reduce approach but I'm AFK to test. Something like ``do.call(`+`, lapply(.SD, is.na))`` could also work

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this.

```
dat[rowSums(!is.na(dat[, cols, with=FALSE])) > 0,]
    a  b  c
#1: 1  1 NA
#2: 2  2  1
#3: 3  3  2
#4: 4 NA  3
```

Comment: Well, this doesn't fulfill OP's requirements of using a vector of relevant column names ("cols").